# sql not calculating sum correctly

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got the following sql query, it seems to be returning data, but the sum of the invoice_total (4th column) is not calculating properly. At the moment although I have about 50 records in purchase files with the duplicate supplierID, I currently only have 4 individual supplier records filled with the invoice_total. The returned result is not what I have put in.

```
SELECT p.orderID, s.supplier, SUM(IFNULL(pl.line_price,0)) AS total_order, SUM(IFNULL(p.invoice_total,0)) AS invoice_total  
  FROM purchase p 
  LEFT JOIN purchase_line pl 
  ON p.orderID = pl.orderID 
  LEFT JOIN supplier s 
  ON p.supplierID = s.supplierID 
  WHERE (p.date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-30')
  GROUP BY p.supplierID 
  ORDER BY p.supplierID ASC
```

Table definitions are as follows along with sample data
purchase

```
  orderID, date, supplierID, supplier_ref, invoice_total
  001, 2015-11-15, 1, abc, 11300000 
  002, 2015-11-15, 2, def, 23900000
  003, 2015-11-15, 3, ghi, 68265000
  004, 2015-11-15, 4, jkl, 31300000
  005, 2015-11-15, 5, lmn, [Null]

  purchase_line
  orderID, item_price, qty, line_price
  001,100000,50000, (that would be line_price*qty)
  001,200000,25000,
  001,300000,10000,
  002,400000,20000,
  003,300000,30000,
  004,200000,20000,

  supplier
  supplierID, supplier, address1, address2, zip
  1, Apple 
  2, Microsoft,
  3, Oracle
  4, SAP
  5, IBM
```

The data that seems to be returned for the total_invoice field is. Bear in mind I have only populated one row of data with the invoice_total filled in. However I have lots of records with Null in that field which are associated to supplier 1 or supplier 2.

```
  supplierID, invoice_total
  1, 700600000
  2, 95600000
  3, 136530000
```

Comment: Why are you using `LEFT JOIN`s? Is the sum correct when you use `INNER JOIN`s instead ? By using the left joins you can get duplicates which can result in an incorrect sum.

Comment: Great, already been marked down. Jaco, I get the same result when I use an inner join

Comment: I didn't down vote you. Can you please provide your table definitions and some example data ?

Comment: I assume your purchase line table has multiple rows per purchase. This means that your invoice total duplicates for every purchase line. You need to join in the sum of the invoice total as a separate subquery.

Comment: Ah Rabbit, I think you're on the right track, I may indeed need a subquery to get the right calculation, thought this method was far too easy

Comment: Note that your `group by` usage is invalid SQL because it does not include the `orderID` column - every other DBMS will reject that statement (except MySQL which chooses to return random (aka "indeterminate) data instead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of the `invoice_totals` are incorrect as `invoice_total` values can be repeated, as each order can have multiple rows in `purchase_line`. In order to resolve this, you will need to aggregate twice, first on `supplierid` and `order` and finally on `supplierid` only.

```
 SELECT supplierid ,
       SUM(total_order) AS total_order ,
       SUM(invoice_total) AS invoice_total
 FROM   ( SELECT    p.supplierID ,
                p.orderID ,
                SUM(IFNULL(pl.line_price, 0)) AS total_order ,
                IFNULL(p.invoice_total, 0) AS invoice_total
        FROM        purchase p
                LEFT JOIN purchase_line pl ON p.orderID = pl.orderID
                LEFT JOIN supplier s ON p.supplierID = s.supplierID
        WHERE   ( p.date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-30' )
        GROUP BY    p.supplierID ,
                p.orderID
       ) details
 GROUP BY   supplierID
 ORDER BY   supplierID ASC
```

Just to clarify the inner query, for Apple this
`IFNULL(p.invoice_total, 0)` picks one of the three (duplicate) invoice totals. You can achieve the same using `MIN(IFNULL(p.invoice_total, 0))` or `MAX(IFNULL(p.invoice_total, 0))` as the invoice_totals are all duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your take on this Jaco, the query above is producing the same calculated results as my initial query.

Comment: Thank you! that did the trick, don't quite understand subqueries yet and more importantly when I should use them. Walking through your code